Парсиг htm файла с помощью CMD/bat
Дан лог  файлы формата htm результат работы программы для бэкапа iperius
Задача парсить этот файл с условием если найдено "Бэкап выполнен успешно" выполнить echo "0" >C:\result.txt, если не найдено "1". перепробовал десятки вариантов решения не нашел, подскажите
Отчет Iperius Backup

Бэкап  локально
Бэкап выполнен успешно

Начало бэкапа:  17.12.2024 23:00:44
Конец бэкапа:   18.12.2024 0:15:38   (1 час, 14 Минуты, 54 Секунды)
Размер скопировнных данных: 110,2 GB
Количество обработанных файлов: 50134
Вид исключения: Служба
Компьютер/Аккаунт:  SERVER / СИСТЕМА
Версия Windows: Майкрософт Server 2019 Std.(64-разрядная) (B.17763)


$ grep -q 'Бэкап выполнен успешно' лог && echo чего-там вам нужно. но, конечно, это не убогий ms/windows shell надо использовать, а какой-нибудь более полноценный.

ОС Windows на линуксе задача решается очень просто. Надо на Windows и типовыми средствами желательно

типовыми средствами - не, ну, вообще-то нетиповых средств я вам и не предлагал. более полноценный shell, равно как и программ grep - это всё описано в стандарте posix. а ms/windows типа как "содержит поддержку posix". так что всё - в рамках "типовых средств".

Да, уже 2024 год на исходе, а в винду так типовые средства и не завезли. Ну хоть зато поставить их туда можно.

findstr /C:"Бэкап выполнен успешно" C:\result.txt >nul && echo 0 || echo 1

Но есть нюанс, кириллица должна быть в кодировке cp866, иначе находить не будет, цена command.com

Спасибо по вашему примеру решил свою задачу
chcp 1251 >nul
find.exe /I путь до файла .htm "Бэкап выполнен успешно" >nul && echo 0 > 777.txt || echo 1 777.txt
exit

@Тимофей Бор Эту задачу можно решить PowerShell в UTF8 кодировке
